# How to clear the row named "Unnamed" in pandas which is merged with all the rows?

Tags: python, pandas

I wanna work on this dataset but as you can see in the image, I see an unnamed row which is before the index[0]. But when I check the first row to delete it, I see that it kinda merges with the data in the index [0] in dataFrame. So i tried deleting the first row but then it still merged with next row and then I searched for all, and its there in all rows. Any thoughts on how to get rid of it.? Any help is much appreciated. The code and the output is below:

[Snippet of the dataframe head including the "Unnamed" row][1]

`df.iloc[0]`

````
   2834897563                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
   2906056396
   Unnamed: 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
   3.7
   data analyst intern                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
   model based systems engineering (mbse) and req...
   Mid-Atlantic Physician                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
   General Motors
   Rockville                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
   Warren
   MD                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
   MI
   nan                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
   69.0
   nan.1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
   101.0
   https://www.glassdoor.com/partner/jobListing.htm? pos=1801&ao=4121&s=58&guid=0000016511cb3879892978f692c8947b&src=GD_JOB_AD&t =SR&extid=1&exst=OL&ist=&ast=OL&vt=w&slr=true&rtp=0&cs=1_5a2aa76f&cb=153360 1855999&jobListingId=2834897563                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
   https://www.glassdoor.com/partner/jobListing.h...
   ['include', 'analysis.', 'to', 'provide', 'hedis', 'includes', 
   'review', 'clinical', 'the', 'risk', 'mid', 'information', 
   'students', 'works', 'our', 'that', 'systems', 'create', 'ncqa', 
   'process', 'assistant', 'other', 'adjustment', 'data', 'querying', 
   'interns', 'identified']    ['areapplied', 'teams', 'gmvehicle', 
   'these', ...
    Newark                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    Detroit
    MI
    ['1', '50']                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    ['10000']
    HealthCare                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    Manufacturing
    Name: 0, dtype: object```


 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SSAH.png
````

Comment: What is the dataset and how are you reading it into a `DataFrame`?

Comment: The dataset contains job listings from glassdoor and its already in a csv file. The problem is, there are no column names hence the first row gets replaced as the column names I guess. Any thoughts on that? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a column you do not want, and that's why you see its value on every row you look at.

To validate that the case you can look at your DataFrame's columns by (the second column should be the column you do not want):

```
df.columns
```

If that's really the case you can delete the column from the entire DF by:

```
df.drop(1,axis=1)
```

Notice this will only return the DF without the column, if you want to delete in df object itself, you can add inplace=True.

The relevant docs is here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html

Comment: Thanks for the tip!!.I tried and got rid of the column. But after I realized that there are no column headers/names and hence the the very first row becomes the column headers. Any thoughts on that?? Thank you

Comment: Why not adding headers in the original files? If you want to change it with pandas you can change the columns using the function rename (if you need the first row as a data remember to add it as a new row before so you won't lost the row) https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html#